# Add binaries to PATH with Ansible

Tags: bash, path, elixir, ansible

I'm trying to install the [Kiex](https://github.com/taylor/kiex) Version manager for the [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/install.html) programming language using Ansible.

These are the plays I use for this:

```
- name: Kiex Installation
  hosts: web
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: deployer
  tasks:
    - shell: \curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/taylor/kiex/master/install | bash -s
    - name: Add Kiex Bin to Path
      lineinfile:
        dest: /home/deployer/.bashrc
        regexp: '^test -s'
        line: '[[ -s "$HOME/.kiex/scripts/kiex" ]] && source "$HOME/.kiex/scripts/kiex"'
    - name: Reload Path
      shell: source /home/deployer/.bashrc
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
    - shell: echo $PATH
      register: pathul
    - debug:
        var: pathul

- name: Elixir Installation
  hosts: web
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: deployer
  tasks:
    - shell: echo $PATH
      register: pathul
    - debug:
        var: pathul
    - name: Install Elixir Version
      command: /home/deployer/.kiex/bin/kiex list
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
        chdir: /home/deployer/
    - name: Set Elixir Version as Default
      shell: kiex default 1.4
```

The Installation of Kiex is a success and if I log in to the remote Machine I am able to run it simply by using the `kiex` command. I can do this because I sourced the binaries in "~/.kiex/scripts/kiex". When I echo the `$PATH` variable it shows the kiex binaries path `/home/deployer/.kiex/bin` in it:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/deployer/.kiex/bin:/home/deployer/.kiex/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

However the `kiex`, `kiex list` and even the `/home/deoployer/.kiex/bin/kiex list` in the **Elixir Installation** Play shown above fail with the message:

```
TASK [Set Elixir Version as Default] *******************************************
fatal: [local-web-2]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "kiex default 1.4", "delta": "0:00:00.002042", "end": "2017-01-26 22:13:32.898082", "failed": true, "rc": 127, "start": "2017-01-26 22:13:32.896040", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: kiex: not found", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

Also the `pathul` variable that registered the result of echoing the path via ansible doesn't contain `/home/deployer/.kiex/bin`:

```
"stdout": "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

How can I make the `kiex` command work properly via Ansible?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the full, absolute path, like you tried in the `Install Elixir Version` task, but mind that you have a typo, both, in the example and in the explanation you posted:

> ```
> command: /home/deoployer/.kiex/bin/kiex list
> ```
>
> [ ] even the `/home/deoployer/.kiex/bin/kiex list` [ ] fail[s]

It should likely be `deployer`, like in the first play, not `deoployer`.

There is no reason otherwise for Ansible to fail with "*kiex: not found*" message, if you provide the correct path.

---

Explanations regarding other tasks:

- Quoting `man bash`:

  > When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists.

  So your `~/.bashrc` is not even read when you execute tasks with Ansible, because it's not an interactive session.

  This is for example why your `pathul` variable does not contain changes applied in the `~/.bashrc`.
- The following two tasks run separate bash processes. The environment sourced in the first task has no influence on the environment of the second:

  ```
  - name: Reload Path
    shell: source /home/deployer/.bashrc
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash
  - shell: echo $PATH
    register: pathul
  ```

Comment: I did have deployer in my playbook. The typo was just in the stackoverflow sample. Regarding the ~/.bashrc not being read, I did suspect there was something wrong about it. Where should I put `[[ -s "$HOME/.kiex/scripts/kiex" ]] && source "$HOME/.kiex/scripts/kiex"'` ?

Comment: I don't know. It depends on the os and distribution. And I advised to use the full path.

Comment: I use Ubuntu Xenial.

Comment: I repeat: for what you have shown in the question use the full path. I have no idea what you are planning to do with the Elixir or how you are planning to use it.